# Custom Templatetags not working properly

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm trying to send data to a TemplateTags called order_details. This templatetags looks for info in database then render the informations list calling another template. When i print just before returning i got the html showing up in the logfile. But nothing show in the rendered page.

```
@register.filter
def order_details(data):
params = EParamCmd.objects.filter(command=data.id, default=False)
dictfunction = {}
for p in params:
    if p.param.typ == 'function':
        dictfunction[p.param.name_inf] = CustomFunction.objects.get(name_inf=p.value)
t = get_template('Formulaire/order-details-params.html')
c = {'params': params, 'func': dictfunction}
LOG.info(t.render(c))
return str(t.render(c))
```

The LOG.info shows the html that should be displayed in this template:

```
{% load tags %}
<h4>Liste des paramètres :</h4>
        {{order|order_details}}
```

When i return 'Hello' in the templatetags it show up.

Thanks.

Comment: You should show the contents of order-details-params.html. However, this isn't a job for a filter, it's a job for template tag - specifically, an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). That will take care of rendering the template for you, with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for thoose who took time trying to answer but it was entirely my fault. Seems like it was some caches issues on my end.

Apologize.